What's the relevance of geometric rigidity/flexibility to physics?
I'm currently working on a mathematics research problem in differential geometry that deals with the rigidity of closed manifolds described by non-trivial induced metrics. I'm curious what the implications of non-rigidity and rigidity are in geometry-heavy fields in physics, if there are any. I would imagine that spacetime, for example, is probably a non-rigid manifold out of necessity. Does the presence of matter/energy induce non-trivial deformations to spacetime? I guess what I'm really asking is whether or not spacetime curvature is a deformation to it as a manifold. If so, is it also necessarily flexible?
I'm referring to non-rigid manifolds as those that have non-trivial deformations and flexible manifolds as one having a non-trivial deformation that can be carried out infinitesimally.
I'd be most interested to hear if non-rigidity/flexibility comes up outside of GR-related topics.

What do you mean by "rigidity of (closed) manifolds"?

@ValterMoretti For a rigid manifold, the only "deformations" you can allow to its metric would be isometries, so rigid motions (translations and rotations). My reference to non-rigidity is the generalization of flexible polyhedra to smooth manifolds that arise in physics. Not necessarily closed.

I would suggest posting this question on MathSE, because it is always better to talk to mathematicians about mathematical concepts than to physicists. They will know what you are talking about, and so will more likely link this with the realm of physics. If you absolutely want to leave this question on PhySE, please make a mathematical introduction to the concepts you are referring to.

So rigid manifolds are manifolds which admit isometries ? The others are flexible? I think I am not right, I suspect that I am not understanding your notion of deformation…

Well, rigid structures (such as e.g. affine manifolds; think SR) and flexible structures (such as e.g. differential manifolds; think GR) both appear in physics.

Canonical transformations on a symplectic manifold is an example of an infinite dimensional flexible structure.

Local conformal transformations are rigid (flexible) if the spacetime dimension is $d\geq 3$ ($d\leq 2$), respectively, cf. e.g. this & this Phys.SE posts.
One may argue this is related to that we know how to quantize 1D strings and 0D particles but not higher-dimensional membranes, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.


More generally, rigidity/flexibility are important facts that underscore the nature of, and have consequences for, the physical systems at hand.

I think there are both mathematical and physical aspect concerning the question of rigidity vs. flexibility.
Let's illustrate the question by the example of a classical field $\varphi$ defined on Minkowski space $\mathbb R^{1,3}$. Which is subject to some physical laws given by a (hyperbolic) partial differential equation.
The question of rigidity is exemplified by the question of regularity conditions for $\varphi$.
Mathematical aspect:
From a mathematical point, different regularity assumptions for $\varphi$ may have technical advantages. E.g.,

If we assume that $\varphi$ is real analytic, i.e, $\varphi \in C^\omega(\mathbb R ^{1,3})$, it is locally possible to write $\varphi$ as a power series.
If we assume that $\varphi$ is smooth, i.e, $\varphi  \in C^\infty(\mathbb R ^{1,3})$, we can have symmetry of partial derivatives, e.g., $ \partial_\mu \partial_\nu\varphi = \partial_\nu \partial_\mu \varphi$. Further, we may use particions of unity as a mathematical tool
For the solution theory, it can be helpful to consider $\varphi$ with less regularity. E.g.,one might be interested in distributional $\varphi$ such as Green's functions.
In order to apply methods of functional analysis, it can be helpful, if the space of considered $\phi$ forms a Hilbert-space.

Physical aspect:
There are also physical aspects to the question of rigidity

Some mathematical solutions, such as distributional solutions, might be considered as unphysical solutions, which are only mathematical idealizations. E.g, physical wave-functions are typically differentiable.

The laws of physics should be rigid in the sense that they uniquely define the physical solutions. E.g., the solutions of Maxwell's equations $\partial^\mu \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}$, are not unique. Nonetheless, they are rigid in the sense, that the solutions are unique up to gauge transformations. Thus, if the physical solutions are identified with the equivalence classes modulo gauge transformations. Maxwell's equations are rigid.

The regularity conditions shouldn't be too rigid. E.g., if only $\varphi \in C^\omega$ are considered. Then constraints on initial data are too restrictive. Some kind of locality, is usually considered to be principle in classical physics. In particular, what is the case on earth does not fix what is the case in some distant galaxy. This is in conflict with  $\varphi \in C^\omega$ due to the identity theorem.


